# SQL: populate a table with variables defined in another table

Tags: sql, sqlite

i have Commissions_table that stores values for a varibale i have listed in a Calls_table. like so

```
EmployeeID      MKM    TKM    LO    
Joe             5      10     15 
John            7      14     21
```

i need to be able to get sum of the column in my Calls_table but replace the variable with the ammount stored in the commissions_table

```
EmployeeID     CommissionType  TypeOfCall  Call#
Joe               MKM            DC          182
Joe               MKM            DC          182
john              TKM            DC          150
John              TKM            DC          160
john              LO             NC          180
```

i need the query to return the sum for the CommissionType for each employee where TypeOfCall is DC and swap out the variable listed in the CommissionType column for the value listed in the Commission_table according to EmployeeID, because the values vary per ID. it also needs to be distinct for the Call# because two invoices are often written up for the same call, but the employees are only paid one commission per call.

so the desired outcome would be like this, the variable in Calls.CommissionType is MKM for joe on call 182 for example, i want to populate a cell that is equal to whatever value is listed in the commission table for that employee. the value for joe in MKM is 5 in the commission table, so for the example the total commission returned on the query would be 5, because the Call# would be dinstinct, and only one commission amount would be returned, and the amount returned for john would be 28, because there would be two amounts added in the returned query because the third listed for john is NC and only DC is needed. so the returned query would look like:

```
EmployeeID     TotalCommission 
John           28
Joe            5
```

i was researching linking the primary key (Calls.EmployeeID) with a foreign key (Commissions.EmployeeID) but still am confused about how i would replace the variable in the calls table. if this is not possible does anyone have any ideas where i could reach a similar outcome?

Comment: Trying to understand what you are looking to do exactly, your example Calls_table has multiple rows with the same types of commission for the same employeeid, is this on purpose or copy/paste error?

Comment: SELECT Distinct Calls.EmployeeID, Calls.CommissionType, December.DR, Commission.TKm
FROM Calls
INNER JOIN Commissions
ON December.EmployeeID=Commissions.EmployeeID
and CommissionType='TKM'         but this only returns one type of commission at a time, and it doesnt replace the variables, it only lists the amount of the variables next to the actual variable and cant figure out how to get the sum from the query.

Comment: And the variables listed are just one example, there are three there TKM, MKM, and LO. the calls table lists all employees calls, so there will be alot of variables that repeat. there are two options to be entered in TypeOfCall, either NC or DC, i need to only return the DC.

Comment: Are you wanting to sum the CommissionType column?  That is not a numeric field in your example schema.

Comment: thats what im saying, i am a manager, and i have amounts each employee makes listed in the Commissions table. that information is privileged so i cant have it viewable by anyone who used the calls table. so i need to use the values listed under the variables in the commissions table to replace their respective variables listed in the calls table. is that even possible? or at least list the values next to the corresponding values in the call table and then add up the sum. i will edit my post and show you the desired outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I worked on this in SQL fiddle so you can test the solution there:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3b815/12/0

Anyhow I get these results:

Joe         5
John            28

I ignored case so both John and john are the same person

The indented sub query uses a case statement to sum depending on what the commission_type is.  Then I sum the totals from that so each employees total commission is shown.  If you run the sub-query you will see it uses the distinct clause to handle the multiple invoicing.

```
SELECT 
EmployeeID,
SUM(CommissionTotal) AS CommissionTotal
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT
    Calls.Call#,
    Calls.EmployeeID,
    Calls.CommissionType,
    Calls.TypeOfCall,
    CASE 
    WHEN Calls.CommissionType = 'MKM' THEN SUM(Commissions.MKM)
    WHEN Calls.CommissionType = 'TKM' THEN SUM(Commissions.TKM) 
    WHEN Calls.CommissionType = 'LO' THEN SUM(Commissions.LO)
    END AS CommissionTotal
    FROM Calls
    LEFT JOIN Commissions 
    ON Calls.EmployeeID=Commissions.EmployeeID
    WHERE TypeOfCall = 'DC'
    GROUP BY Calls.Call#,
    Calls.EmployeeID, 
    Calls.CommissionType,
    Calls.TypeOfCall) a
GROUP BY 
EmployeeID
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is awesome. One thing, the schema you provided i was able to add another row to the table with the same call number and it didnt count it, when i used the code on my actual sql editor it selects all calls regardless of the distinct call#. i can easily fix this by assigning a null value for duplicate invoices, but that leaves room for error...any ideas? im using the sql plug-in for firefox, any chance this is just an oversight on certain syntax on the part of firefox?

Comment: Glad this helped!  That is interesting about your discrepancy using the plug-in.  Now I had the SQL Fiddler set in SQL 2008 mode, What SQL flavor was your Firefox plug-in set too?  I know you are working in SQLlite for your actual issue but I think the query I wrote should be fine in that.  Perhaps your tools is doing the grouping before processing the distinct part?

Comment: Actually I think the way I wrote the Create Table and Insert Statements in Fiddler (SQL 2008 mode) is not compatible with SQLlite.  But I am sure there is another way to build the schema in SQLlite that I just don't know.

Comment: You can create tables from formatted text pretty easily with the text to dll button. Sometimes you have to help out [the parser](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0lcy3.png) Here's [the fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/781df/1) I created

Comment: Thanks Conrad I didn't know about that feature.